# Cookies set by AngularJS are ignored after browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, cookies

I am creating an Angularjs single page app with SQL, Angularjs, Node.js, and Express, which has login using passport and basic auth. When a user logs in they are able to access routes to edit items in the database. This all works correctly, the problem is that the cookies are only sent as long as the browser doesn't refresh.

If the browser refreshes, the token is no longer sent with the request, so the user isn't able to access the routes anymore, because there's no token with the request. If you look at the cookies in the browser, however, the token is still there and as long as the server hasn't restarted, the token should still be valid.

There are also other cookies there that are set by Google Analytics, but they get sent with the request every time. And if I set a cookie in `app.run`, it does persist and get sent with the request every time, it's only the cookies created with the login factory that aren't sent after the browser refreshes.

My login factory looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

import * as customFunctions from '../../shared/methods/common-functions.js';

const userLoggingRESTResources = (app) => {

  app.factory('userLoggingRESTResources', ['$http', '$base64', '$cookies', '$window', ($http, $base64, $cookies, $window) => {
    return (user, callback) => {
      return {
        signIn: (user, callback) => {
          var encoded = $base64.encode(user.username + ':' + user.password);
          $http.get('/auth/login', {
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded
              }
            })
            .success((data) => {

              $cookies.put('token', data.token);
              $cookies.put('interopAdmin', data.admin);
              $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
              $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = data.token;
              callback(null);
            })
            .error((data) => {
              callback(data);
            })
        }

      };
    }


  }])
}

module.exports = userLoggingRESTResources;
```

My login route looks like this:

```js
  router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('basic', {
    session: false
  }), (req, res) => {
    let userJSON = {
      randomString: req.user.dataValues.randomString,
      id: req.user.dataValues.id
    };
    res.req.headers.authorization = 'hahaha';
    for (let key in res.req.rawHeaders) {
      if (res.req.rawHeaders[key].slice(0, 5) === 'Basic') {
        res.req.rawHeaders[key] = 'Basic xxxx';
      }

    }
    req.user.$modelOptions.instanceMethods.generateToken(userJSON, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          msg: 'error generating token'
        });
      }

      res.status('200').header('token', token).json({
        token: token,
        'admin': req.user.dataValues.isAdmin
      });
    });
  });
```

I'm using the [eat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eat) module from npm to handle decoding the token:

```js
'use strict';

const eat = require('eat');
const models = require('../models');
const User = models.User;
const clc = require('cli-color');

module.exports = (secret) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.cookies.token || req.headers.token || req.body.token || req.headers.authorization;
    if (!token) {
      console.log(clc.white.bgRed('no token in request'));
      return res.status(401).json({
        msg: 'not authorized'
      });
    }
    eat.decode(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(clc.white.bgRed('Error, login failed:   '), err);
        return res.status(401).json({
          msg: 'not authorized'
        });
      }

      User.findOne({
          where: {
            id: decoded.id
          }
        })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            console.log(clc.white.bgRed('user not found'));
            return res.status(401).json({
              msg: 'not authorized'
            });
          }

          req.user = user;
          next();
        })
        .error((error) => {
          console.log(clc.white.bgRed('Error:  '), err);
          return res.status(401).json({
            msg: 'not authorized'
          });
        });
    });
  };
};
```

If there's another part of the code you would like to see, please let me know. Thanks if advance for all you help!

Comment: use angular-storage for your token https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage

Comment: Just to be clear. You are getting a 'no token in request' error in your console yes?

Comment: @Yashua Yes, you're right, I am getting 'no token in request'.

Comment: Have you confirmed that some of your server tokens are read from `req.cookies`? The way you have it your auth can come from many places and I wonder if it's reading the `req.header` every time and that may then indicate a cookie reading issue as a whole.

Comment: @Yashua Yes, they're read from `req.cookies`, originally I only used `$cookie` to store the token, but when it wasn't working on refresh, I tried storing it in more/different places to see if I could get any of those to be sent after a refresh

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. I was using `/admin/login` for my login route and `/admin/whatever` for the other routes that need auth and so the cookies were set with the path: `/admin/login` and since I only use that route at the first login, that's why the cookie was sent the first time, but not in the subsequent requests.

To fix it I set the path to the root when I set the cookies like this:

`$cookies.put('token', data.token, {'expires': expireDate, 'path': '/'});`

and now the cookies are sent with all requests! Thanks for all the tips and help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You said the cookies are *not* sent, then you said the cookies *are* in the browser.  Those two statements contradict one another. If they are in the browser, maybe your Angular app just needs to read them?  If they are not sent, maybe you need to use some kind of session on the server to store the token/whatever so you can send it back as a cookie.

Comment: The cookies are set by Angular from the data response from the login route and then they exist on the browser, then the cookies are sent from the browser with subsequent $http get requests to my node routes. If the page isn't refreshed, the cookies keep getting sent with each subsequent request and everything works.  But if the browser refreshes, the cookies are still on the browser, but for some reason, they are no longer sent with the requests. Sorry if I didn't phrase it well.